# Unable to use a single Stored Procedure for Listing all items and Selected Items

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to list the State Names as a checklist using sql. i.e if an user land to the page for the first time he should see all the states and when he comes in edit mode he should see all states and selected states must be checked. How can I achieve this using a single stored procedure. I tried this

```
create proc spGetList
AS
Begin
    SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
    FROM State A 
    LEFT JOIN UserPreferedState B ON A.StateId = B.StateId 
    WHERE UserId = 3
End
```

But the problem is I am not sure how to add a new column in stored procedure (say `IsSelected`) and set the value as 1 if that state is selected and set value as 0 is that state is not selected.

Example:

Table: `UserPreferedState`

```
Id  UserId  StateId
-------------------
 1    1        1
 2    1        2
 3    2        1
 4    2        2
 5    3        1
```

Table: `State`

```
Id  StateName
--------------
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI
```

I want the result when `userid = 3` to be:

```
Id  StateName  IsSelected 
--------------------------
1   ABC           1
2   DEF           0
3   GHI           0
```

I want the result when `userid = 1` to be:

```
Id  StateName  IsSelected
-------------------------
1   ABC           1
2   DEF           1
3   GHI           0
```

Comment: Whcih column stores the sselected state value ? And which DBMS you tagged it with mysql and sql server ?

Comment: @CoderofCode DBMS: sql server and the  State  table has StateId and State Description and UserPreferedState  table has Id(PK), StateId, UserId

Comment: Please be more specify as what you want to achieve thru your SP.

Comment: Can you include some test data and your expected output to the question.

Comment: @PareshJ I wanted to add one more column (bit field) and the value as 1 if that state is selected by user and set value as 0 is that state is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy. Here's the fiddle too : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/217ce/2

```
CREATE TABLE state (
StateId INT,
StateName VARCHAR(100)  
);

CREATE TABLE userPreferredState (
Id INT,
UserId INT,
StateId INT
); 

INSERT INTO state (StateId, StateName)
VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'DEF'), (3, 'GHI');

INSERT INTO userPreferredState (Id, UserId, StateId) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (5, 3, 1);

CREATE PROCEDURE getStateListForUser @User int
AS
SELECT 
s.StateId AS Id,
s.stateName,
CASE WHEN (ups.UserId = @User) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS IsSelected
FROM
State s
LEFT JOIN
UserPreferredState ups ON s.StateId = ups.StateId AND ups.UserId = @User
GO
```

To run it, call:

```
EXEC getStateListForUser @User = 1
EXEC getStateListForUser @User = 3
```